# Adding a Django constraint based on data in model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Say I have a simple model like this:

```
class Country:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)

class City:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    country = models.ForeignField('Country', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Hat:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    country = models.ForeignField('Country', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

class Person:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    country = models.ForeignField('Country', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    city = models.ForeignField('City', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    hat = models.ForeignField('Hat', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

In this contrived example, a hat can only be worn in one country, and also a city can only be in one country. However, a person has to have exactly one hat, and one city, assigned to them. The hat and city of a person must then be of the same country as the person is.

I can't see any easy way of doing this with limit_choices_to in the city field, as it can't reference the current data values.

What's the best way of going about this - ideally that would also work with the admin console?

Comment: Why use two fields in the first place? Why not just `city`? You can obtain the country by accessing the country of the city.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The question better reflects my current problem now - maybe the best solution is still to ellide the data into fewer tables somehow, but it doesn't seem possible to me.

Comment: You can use `validate`, if `person.hat.country != person.city.country`, you raise an exception

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect there is no good way to do this, at least from my view point. @FranciscoCouzo if I were to implement that, it would ensure that my data was valid, but it wouldn't integrate well with the admin console at all (although of course I could just write something to the effect of "make sure your hat and city are for the same country as your person!")